# Fail to Commit [ Tortoise Assembla

Tags: tortoisesvn, assembla

Got this message when try to commit new folder to the SVN.

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKCOL request for
```

How can i overcome this error. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This error usually happens when the directory already exists in SVN repository.

Try the following:

- Save your folder outside your SVN working copy
- Undo Add
- Do SVN Update on parent's folder; The folder should me added
- Overwrite this newly added folder with the copy made outside SVN